# Array elements comparison

Tags: java, arrays

I have an object array which is initially empty ie all items are null.

`Object o[]={null,null,null,null,null}`

The class Object has been defined.

```
class Object
{
    int type;
    int x;
    int y;
    Object(int index)
    {
        type = new Random().nextInt(2);
        int[] xValues={25,95,175,245};
        x=xValues[new Random().nextInt(4)];
        y=new Random().nextInt(20)*-150;
        for(int n=0;n<o.length;n++)
        {

            try
            {
                if(o[n].y==y && o[n].x==x)
                {
                    //This is a contradiction and so change the values of x and y as desired
                }
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }
}
```

I add values for each of the elements of the array now.

```
int i=0;
while(i<5)
{
    o[i] = new Object(i);
    i++;
}
```

Before adding I want to compare the properties of that object with all the other elements of the array so I have incorporated it in the constructor of the class. So far so good.

Now, depending on my results(to make sure it doesn't contradict with other objects of the array), I modify the object's properties that I am going to add. 
However, since I loop only once, I may have made a contradiction with one of the objects that I have already gone over. I have no way to check that.

How shall I make sure that each of the object of the array doesn't contradict with any other?

PS: By contradict I mean that both x and y properties of an object are the same.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: What stopped you to write `boolean contains(Object[] array, Object element)` method ? imho, it's quicker to  write it than asking here...

Comment: Exact same properties of both objects is just one case of a contradiction. There are other conditions also.

Comment: Your explanation of contradiction contradicts with your use of the word in the previous paragraph. The first time you say it is about contradiction of the different items of a collection, the second time it is about different properties of the same instance. And never use whe already used class names for yor own classes. Name it MyObject or, better, give some name from the theme it is all about (Car, House, Aquiaintance...)

Comment: Your code is not compilable, please replace it with real one. Your attributes should be private, object is wrong class name, try is ambiguous and it doesn't have catch block - dude, you don't know what you are doing! What your Object should do?

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense.  `Object` does not have an `Object(int)` constructor, and an `Object` instances does not / cannot have `x` and `y` properties.  (And if you have declared your own class with the name `Object` ... you are crazy!)

Comment: @Pranav "There are other conditions also" - Then extract a method of your code! e.g. ``contradicts(lhs: Object, rhs: Object) : boolean``

Answer (score 2):

First of all, come on guys, of course I can compile my own Object class if it is in different package... But I agree it's not a good practice to use such special names for own classes...

It seems, you want to create N Objects...

I'd do that like this

```
package q34350913;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Object {

    // TODO: add your properties...

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final List<Object> list = new LinkedList<Object>();
        final int N = 5;
        while (list.size() < N) {
            final Object newObject = randomCreation();
            if (isOkToAdd(list, newObject)) {
                list.add(newObject);
            }
        }
    }

    private static Object randomCreation() {
        return null; // TODO !!!
    }

    private static boolean isOkToAdd(final List<Object> list, final Object newObject) {
        for (final Object listItem : list) {
            if (contradicts(listItem, newObject)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static boolean contradicts(final Object listItem, final Object newObject) {
        return false; // TODO !!!
    }
}
```

but you have to implement your own versions of `randomCreation` and `contradicts`, see TODOs.

Answer (score 0):

1: you should use MyObject (because Object already exists !)

2: use a while loop in your constructor

```
boolean not_done=true;

while (not_done)
{
// once again
// ...

if  ( // no contradiction
  not_done=false;
```

that's all

Answer (score 0):

You should move the `Random()` logic out of the `Object` constructor, run it in the class that runs the `Object`-creating loop and just pass the prepared number into the `Object's` constructor. There are several reasons for that:

1) Putting this much logic in the constructor is not a clean approach and should be avoided. Constructor should create the object, it may also invoke methods that set it up, but should not contain too much logic itself. Code clean :-)

2) If you create the randomised number in the parent object, you will be able to iterate through the `Object`[] to make sure that none of the previously created Objects contain the new number :-)